# Filling 2D list with nested loops skips over and repeats values unexpectedly in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function which takes in a 1D list `li` and turns it in to a 2D list of 10 columns and X rows. (The length of `li` is guaranteed to be divisible by 10.) The function will copy elements from the input `li` to the output in order filling the first column of the 2D list all the way, then filling the second column all the way, and so on until it has copied all elements from `li`.

Here is an example of my desired input and output:

Input:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T']
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I', 'K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S'], 
 ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T']]
```

Here is my code:

```
def transform(li) :
rows = int(len(li) / 10)
result = [[" "] * 10] * rows

for col in range(10) :
    for row in range(rows) :
        result[row][col] = li.pop(0)

return result
```

And given the same input as above here is what it is outputting:

```
[['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T'], 
 ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T']]
```

After using print statements to try and debug it seems like it is assigning the entire column at once. So it assigns both rows in the first column to 'A' then overrides that when it assigned them both to 'B'.  I can't see why the code is doing this! All help is appreciated!

Comment: So, when there is enough elements for 3 rows, is `'C'` the first element in row 3?

Comment: Yes it is meant to fill in the first column all the way and then fill in the second column all the way and so on. I will add that to the post thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you "multiply" a list it copies the object references, not the underlying objects.  So each row of the outer list is actually referencing the same inner list object.

```
result = [[" "] * 10] * rows
```

To create a new list for each row, you can do the following:

```
result = [[" "] * 10 for _ in range(rows)]
```

Note: Use `xrange` instead of `range` if using Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

You can use the [List comprehension notation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) to reshape your array into a matrix. Like this

```
some_list[start:end:step]
```

## Code

```
def transform(li):
    rows = len(li) // 10
    return [li[i:len(li):rows] for i in range(rows)]
```

## An input example

```
arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
       'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
       'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

## Correspondant output

```
['A', 'D', 'G', 'J', 'M', 'P', 'S', 'V', 'Y', '2']
['B', 'E', 'H', 'K', 'N', 'Q', 'T', 'W', 'Z', '3']
['C', 'F', 'I', 'L', 'O', 'R', 'U', 'X', '1', '4']
```

## Explanation

The *"condensed"* part here is the `li[i:len(li):rows]` so let's explain that

- The first `i` inside the `[]` refers to the start of the subarray
- The second one `len(i)` is the end of the subarray
- The third one `rows` is the **step**. Here the step is equal to the number of rows since we want to jump by the number of rows to match the expected output in your question

We extract a *sub-array* for each possible row, which is what the `[... for i in range(rows)]` is for

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way of doing what you're attempting:

```
def transform(li):
    l1 = []
    l2 = []

    for i, a in enumerate(li):
        if i % 2 == 0: l1.append(a)
        else: l2.append(a)

    return [l1,l2]
```

A benefit of doing it this way is that it will work for lists of any length, instead of requiring you to hardcode the # of elements.